# Why does docker-compose not lookup the IP address from the MySQL container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My own_app requires a MySQL database. The problem is that the own_app container needs to ip of the MySQL database. My aim is to solve this issue by using docker-compose.yml.

**Dockerfile**

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

Based on the [Wordpress example](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/) the docker-compose.yml has been slightly modified as follows:

```
version: '2'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   own_app:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: own_app:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_DB_HOST: db:3306
volumes:
    db_data:
```

but it inserts `db:3306`

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://db:3306/database_name"
```

instead of an IP address

**Problem**

The sed statement that resides in the `docker-entrypoint.sh` works well, i.e. it replaces localhost with the $MYSQL_DB_HOST environment variable. The problem is that docker-compose returns `db:3306` instead of `<ip>:3306`

**Question**

Why is docker-compose not looking up the IP address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables in docker-compose are just strings, it doesn't know if it's a hostname or any other text. The only parsing that's done is to expand variables in the `${varname}` syntax.

For connecting containers together, you don't want IP addresses anyway, they can change. Use the DNS based discovery which will resolve "db" from the service name in any other containers that are on the same network.